# getting error Pickle data was truncated. using sockets and openCV

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, pickle

my program is simple. The server is gonna send his video to the client with his username. For me, the username sending part is something that is very important. And when I am sending a username it gives the error `_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated`.

Here's my code:

server.py

```
import socket, cv2, pickle, struct

# Socket Create
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('HOST IP:', host_ip)
port = 9999
socket_address = (host_ip, port)

# Socket Bind
server_socket.bind(socket_address)

# Socket Listen
server_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT:", socket_address)
Header_length = 20

# Socket Accept
while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:', addr)
    if client_socket:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while (vid.isOpened()):
            img, frame = vid.read()
            resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame , (920,690))
            a = pickle.dumps(resized_frame)
            username = 'xyz£¬Khajahost'
            client_socket.send(f"{len(bytes(username , 'utf-8')):<{Header_length}}".encode('utf-8') + username.encode('utf-8') )
            message = f"{len(a):<{Header_length}}".encode('utf-8') + a
            client_socket.sendall(message)

            cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO', frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord('q'):
                client_socket.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket, cv2, pickle, struct

# create socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)  # paste your server ip address here
port = 9999
client_socket.connect((host_ip, port))  # a tuple
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
while True:
    recieved_data = client_socket.recv(20).decode('utf-8')
    print(recieved_data)
    if not recieved_data:
        continue
    username = client_socket.recv(int(recieved_data)).decode('utf-8')
    print(username , len(username))

    frame_data_length = client_socket.recv(20).decode('utf-8')
    frame_data = client_socket.recv(int(frame_data_length))

    while len(frame_data) < int(recieved_data):
        remainig_data = int(recieved_data) - len(frame_data)
        frame_data += client_socket.recv(remainig_data)

    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
    cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
client_socket.close()
```

Any idea why this error Is happening and any help to resolve this issue, please.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Getting pickle data truncated error while working with sockets and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472401/getting-pickle-data-truncated-error-while-working-with-sockets-and-python)

Comment: no it's not the same . I only asked that question and this question is also asked by me . they are different

Comment: please check the code. I have mentioned the username stuff there. When I am sending the username along with picture data it is giving me an error